# Run one mutation with different arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

In the below component, user can enter the results. Here each of the results are individual row of 'RESULT' table in database.
I have a mutation which will update the individual result. 
Here when user click the save button, all the results will be saved.
To achieve this, the UPDATE_RESULT mutation need to be called with different argument for each result.

Can any one suggest me how to do this?

If you have any different approach to implement this functionality, please share that also.

Resolver

```
const updateResult = async (_, {number, input: { entry, entered_by, status, old_status, result_modified, in_spec, cancelled, optional }}, {user, prisma}) => {
if(!user){
    throw new Error('Not Authenticated')
}
const updatedResult = await prisma.updateResult({
    data: {
        entry,
        entered_by,
        entered_on,
        status,
        old_status,
        result_modified,
        in_spec,
        cancelled,
        optional
    },
    where: {
        number
    }
})

return updatedResult
}
```

Component

```
import React, { Suspense, useState, Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import ErrorBoundary from '../ErrorBoundary';
import { useMutation } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const UPDATE_RESULT = gql`
mutation updateResult($number: Int!, $input: updateResultInput){
    updateResult(number: $number, input: $input){
     number
     name
}
}
`

export default function ResultDetails({results}){
   const [entry, setEntry] = useState({});
   const [inSpec, setInSpec] = useState({});

   const [mutation, { loading, error }] = useMutation(UPDATE_RESULT)


   const isInSpec = (val, max_val, min_val) => {
    if(val >= min_val && val<= max_val) return true;
    return false;
   }

   const saveResults = () => {
    for(let res in entry){
        console.log(entry[res], entry)
    }
    // run mutation 'update result' to save all the entered results
   }
   useEffect(() => {
        results.map(result => {
        let spec = isInSpec(parseInt(entry[result.name]), result.max_val, result.min_val);
        setInSpec({...inSpec, [result.name]: spec})
    })
}, [entry])
return (
    <Suspense>
        <ErrorBoundary>
            <Fragment>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Entry</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>In spec</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {console.log(results)}
                    {results.map(result => (
                        <tr key={result.number}>
                            <td>{result.name}</td>
                            <td>{result.result_type}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input
                                  style={{color: 'red'}}
                                  name={result.name} 
                                  type={result.type === 'numeric' ? "number" : "text"}
                                  value={entry[result.name] || ''}
                                  onChange={(e) => {
                                      setEntry({...entry, [result.name]: e.target.value})
                                    }}
                                />
                            </td>
                            <td>{result.unit}</td>
                            <td>{inSpec[result.name]? 'YES': 'NO'}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button onClick={saveResults}>Save</button>
            </Fragment>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Suspense>
)
}
```

Comment: separate `UPDATE_RESULTS mutation taking array as an argument?

Comment: @xadm That's not possible. Because each result is a separate element of result table.

Comment: ???? show UPDATE_RESULT mutation resolver code

Comment: @xadm added the resolver in the question

Answer (score 0):

1. Your GraphQL mutation is invalid, you declared variables but didn't used them. You should have somthing like this:

```
const UPDATE_RESULT_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation updateResultMutation($number: Int!, $input: updateResultInput){
        updateResult(number: $number, input: $input) {
            number
            name  
        }
    }
`
```

2. To execute mutation with some variables you should use this syntax:

```
          mutation({ variables: {
                number: 1, 
                input: 
                  {
                     inputField: "inputValue",
                     //... more fields from your state
                  } 
          });
```

I'd suggest to rename variables to something more meaningfull -  for example  `mutation -> executeUpdateMutation`

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. Here each result is a separate element in the 'Result' table. So we need to call the update mutation multiple times to update each of the result.